# $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\arctan(-n)}n$ Converge or diverge?

Tags: calculus, inequality

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\arctan(-n)}n$$

Im trying to prove it converges/diverges and I managed to get to this inequality:

Since $\arctan(-n)$ is an odd function then:

$$-\frac{\pi/2}n\leq-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \arctan(n)/n\\ 
\frac{π/2}{n}\geq \sum_{n=1}^\infty\arctan(n)/n$$

Can I proceed from here?

Comment: Please have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation and re-fromat you question accordingly.

Comment: Do you know that $\sum\frac1n$ diverges?

Comment: $n$ doesn’t mean anything outside the sum. Maybe you mean $\frac{\pi/2}{n}\geq \frac{\arctan n}n?$

Answer (score 5):

We have $\arctan(n) \ge \pi/4$ for all $n\ge 1$, hence

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\arctan(n)}{n} \ge \frac{\pi}{4}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} = \infty$$